# how to insert into sql table additional values from second table if primary ids both start with 1?

Tags: sql, primary-key

the supply table:

```
supply_id | title          | author           | price  | amount |
+-----------+----------------+------------------+--------+--------+
| 1         | Лирика         | Пастернак Б.Л.   | 518.99 | 2      |
| 2         | Черный человек | Есенин С.А.      | 570.20 | 6      |
| 3         | Белая гвардия  | Булгаков М.А.    | 540.50 | 7      |
| 4         | Идиот          | Достоевский Ф.М. | 360.80 | 3
```

I am trying to insert into book , all the values from supply:

```
+---------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+--------+
| book_id | title                 | author           | price  | amount |
+---------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+--------+
| 1       | Мастер и Маргарита    | Булгаков М.А.    | 670.99 | 3      |
| 2       | Белая гвардия         | Булгаков М.А.    | 540.50 | 5      |
| 3       | Идиот                 | Достоевский Ф.М. | 460.00 | 10     |
| 4       | Братья Карамазовы     | Достоевский Ф.М. | 799.01 | 2      |
| 5       | Стихотворения и поэмы | Есенин С.А.      | 650.00 | 15     |
+---------+-----------------------+------------------+--------+--------+



  insert into book(title,author,price,amount)
    select * from supply;
```

the primary ids conflict with each other - both tables start with id '1'

```
ERROR 1136: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your columns in `insert` and `select` mismatches. You need to give explicit names of the columns instead of `*` in `SELECT` clause.

Try this:

```
insert into book(title,author,price,amount)
    select title,author,price,amount from supply;
```

Comment: thx, it does work but the ID are counting from 5,6,7,8... how to reset ID to 0 when inserting?

Comment: Why you want to reset it to 0? it should not be changed else your bookid will clash with your supply.id column. it must be auto increment so let it be.